# asp.net HttpPost returning error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My HttpPost using ASP.NET Web API is always returning error from the AJAX request.

My controller:

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:52884", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public string Post(myData m)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1:d}", m.FirstName, m.LastName);
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class myData 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My HTML request:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:52884/api/contact",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName" },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run it on the browser, I get the alert: Error Error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

If I run it using Postman, it works. But I need it in Ajax request because other websites will call my API

Comment: First, URL should be  `/api/contact` only, second thing pass data in model with name `myData `

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the data in model is myData. I paste wrong here. I changed the URL to /api/contact, but still the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I added jsonp to my dataType and it gives me the error: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:52884/api/contact?callback=jQuery1124019591546547214278_1507915886464&FirstName=FName&LastName=LName&_=1507915886465”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just refactor your code in this way:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:{port}", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Route("api/test")]
public string Post(myData model)
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1:d}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);
}

public class myData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And Ajax call:

```
<script>
    model = {
        FirstName: "FName",
        LastName: "LName"
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/test",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: model,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
            alert(err);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope you get an idea from this!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I added jsonp to my dataType and it gives me the error: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:52884/api/contact?callback=jQuery1124019591546547214278_1507915886464&FirstName=FName&LastName=LName&_=1507915886465”.

Comment: @user6824563: why are you using `jsonp?`

Comment: @user6824563: If you're doing `Cross-Origin Requests` you must be enable it in API, which is not included in the answer.

Comment: How can I enable it in API?

Comment: @user6824563: Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: @user6824563: Well this answer is working with `jsonp`, answer updated just put debug point at `Post` method

Comment: Hum... Can I debug an ApiController? I'm calling the AJAX request from a simple HTML file.

Comment: @user6824563: Yup you can, Ajax does the same thing as postman doing..calling controller method.

Comment: I inserted the [EnableCors], but if I remove the jsonp, I get the CORS error

Comment: I put the debug point; however, it did not stop there when I run my html file in the browser

Comment: @user6824563: I would suggest that if you're really not using CORS then please remove it. IF you need to use resource from outside of the project, in that case you need to enable it from both the sides, client as well as server.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Just can't understand why Postman it works, but AJAX call I get Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:52884/api/contact?callback=jQuery112409902197956907268_1507917530625&FirstName=FName&LastName=LName&_=1507917530626”

Comment: @user6824563: Not sure *why* it's completely working check it [here](http://imgr.es/3QF0)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This post is getting too big. I'm going to create another one with the new issue. My browser console also shows: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Answer (score 0):

it returns error, because ajax can't parse the Post method response

```
        [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:{port}", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("api/test")]
    public string Post(myData m)
    {
        return string.Format("{{ \"FirstName\" : \"{0}\", \"LastName\" : \"{1}\" }}", m.FirstName, m.LastName);
    }
```

Comment: It's WeApi not MVC :)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem